# Subprocess error in python

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, subprocess

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
calc=Frame(root)
calc.grid()
root.title("Calculator")
bt=Button(calc,text="3")
bt.grid()
process=subprocess.Popen(['python','imacap.py'],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In given code I created GUI using tkinter in python. While displaying GUI app, I want to run camera capturing app at the same time so after googling it I found solution of using subprocess.Popen. So I created imacap.py and used in it. But now I am facing error as Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/home/mukund/testa.py", line 9, in 
>   process=subprocess.Popen(['python','imacap.py'],
>   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>   NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: You have imported Popen not subprocess. Please use import subprocess

Answer (score 3):

You are importing `Popen` and `PIPE` from `subprocess`. Now you can access `Popen` or `PIPE` directly, no need of `subprocess` as prefix.

If you want to use `subprocess` as prefix then change your import.

`import subprocess`

Then `subprocess.Popen` will work.

Answer (score 2):

you should change your import to "import subprocess"